# Is it a good practice your api bundle depends on another bundle api?

Tags: java, api, osgi

I separate my service bundle and my api bundle. In my api bundle, I have an entity that contains entity from another api bundle. Is it a design problem or is it a good practice?

1. BundleA-api: contains foo.Foo interface
2. BundleB-api: contains bar.Bar interface (which have a Foo member)
3. BundleC-service: import BundleB-api and offer service that implements bar.Bar interface

I hope it's clear ;-)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It is always good if you manage to keep your APIs self contained but that is not always possible. So I don't think depending on another API is always a bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

For convenience you may want to distribute a bundle-all.jar file instead of just the separate ones.

Answer (score 0):

The goal should be to keep APIs as uncoupled as possible using basic JDK types. However, sometimes you really need to use another abstraction or do not want to repeat functionality. As most things in design, it is finding the optimum between opposing forces. In software, you want to minimize coupling and maximize cohesion.

One trick to minimize API coupling is to use a shared type that is in the JDK. Integer & String ids often work well in this regard. For example, in OSGi enRoute the [Authentication](http://enroute.osgi.org/services/osgi.enroute.authentication.api.html) service does not return the [UserAdmin](http://enroute.osgi.org/services/org.osgi.service.useradmin.html) service's User object but it returns the String id of a user. The Authentication service can therefore be used with the User Admin service but it does not mandate it. Potentially, another user database could also be used, leaving the choice to the users of the service as it should be.

Comment: Thanks for the example